# display current date -1 in sybase

Tags: sybase

I am trying to display the previous day's date Sybase using a select query:

```
select dateadd(day,-1,convert(char(10), getdate(), 23))
```

this query displays as `2015-06-18 00:00:00.0`

I expect the output to be `2015-06-18`.

How can I get that?

Answer (score 2):

Try select dateadd(day,-1,convert(Date, getdate(), 365))

Answer (score 1):

Try  select convert(char(10),dateadd(day,-1, getdate() ), 23 )

Dateadd expects a date parameter as the third argument.  In your example you're feeding it a char(10) . Even though implicit conversion from Char->DateTime is supported in Sybase, I would not code to depend on it in this case.

Comment: shorter and better to remember: SELECT DATE(DATEADD(DAY, -10, (getdate()))), if you don´t need yyyy-MM-dd format.

Answer (score 0):

You are telling it to give you hh:mm:ss, so that's what you are getting.

The `23` inside the convert is the format code for `yyyy-mm-ddTHH:mm:ss`  There is no code to get yyyy-mm-dd, the closest you can get is 105 (`dd-mm-yy`) or 110 (`mm-yy-dd`).

If you need yyyy-mm-dd, then you'll have to convert the date to a string(char or varchar), and truncate the parts you don't want.

[Converting Datetime](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc32300.1570/html/sqlug/BABDBAHF.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Well, `datetime` is a binary type. How it is formatted for display is up to you.

`getdate()` returns a `datetime` representing the current date/time. And `dateadd()` returns a `datetime` or `date` value, depending on what it started with (in your case, that would be `datetime`). And when you run your `select` statement, it's getting converted to a string using the default format configured for your Sybase instance. Hence your results.

In a nutshell, you are:

- Converting the `datetime` value to char(10) to get an ISO 8601 format date string (`yyyy-mm-dd`).
- Converting that *back* to a `datetime` value (so the time component is start-of-day)
- Subtracting one day.

The easiest way to get what you want (yesterday's date) is this:

```
dateadd(day,-1, convert(date,getdate()) )
```

Which, when formatted for display, will come out as something like (depending on the default format configured for your Sybase instance) `yyyy-mm-dd`.

Or it might come out like `November 29, 2015`. If you want to ensure that it is an ISO 8601 date representation, you'll need to be explicit about it and cast it a `char` or `varchar`, thus:

```
convert(char(10) , dateadd(day,-1, convert(date,getdate()) ) , 23 )
```

which leaves you with a `char(10)` value containing yesterday's date.

If your version of Sybase doesn't support `date`, you'll have to fall back to what you were doing, but something like this:

```
convert(char(10) , dateadd(day,-1, getdate() ) , 23 )
```